# What does this code mean: public bool HasBars => BarList != null && BarList.Count > 0;?

Tags: c#

I have code on C# and dont understend what it's mean. Is there any analogs of this code&

```
public bool HasBars => BarList != null && BarList.Count > 0;
```

Comment: What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: It was question about syntax. I owervrite code from C# to java and didn't know what is analog code without lambda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the point which is confusing you, is the [expression-bodied-member](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) which is just a syntactic sugar of `C# 6` version.

It is equal to:

```
public bool HasBars 
{
    get
    {
        return BarList != null && BarList.Count > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks? understood. But the BarList != null && BarList.Count > 0 it's not a condition?

Comment: And if it is, Do we can return a condition?

Comment: @AndriyVanDam `BarList != null && Barlist.Count >0` is a simple condition. I don't know what the `BarList` object is. Probably a collection. Thus, the property will return `false` if your `BarList` object is either null or it is empty. If the collection has at least one object, it will return `true`.

Answer (score 4):

It's the same as:

```
public bool HasBars
{
    get
    {
        return BarList != null && BarList.Count > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, understood. But the BarList != null && BarList.Count > 0 it's not a condition? And if it is do we can return a condition?

Comment: @AndriyVanDam we don't return a condition, we return a boolean value evaluated by the condition